# Using #define in C Program

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use `#define` to define a constant in my program. I realize I could use `const`, but I am trying to get a good understanding of `#define`. Could someone please explain why the following code does not work, and should be done instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 20;
typedef int Marray_t[M][M]; //I can't define an M x M array

int main() {
  Marray_t A;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) { //Can't iterate up to M
    A[i] = i;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You must remove `;` after`20`, like this

```
#define M 20
```

Comment: Oh... it was defining it as `20;`. I totally didn't think of that! Thank you.

Comment: Also if like me you are an idiot and put = assignment in define, try removing it. This shows how much I dislike defines and how I don't use C enough any more.